# Move folder from A to B

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

I have a folder with some files inside automatically created once a day. Let's say that folder is named "bla20150309" (so a timestamp is automatically added).

Now I want to move that folder incl. all it's content somewhere else. My code so far:

```
import time
import datetime
import shutil

ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d')

def copyDirectory(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    # Directories are the same
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
    # Any error saying that the directory doesn't exist
    except OSError as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)

copyDirectory("D:/bla%s","E:/hello%s") % (st, st)
```

So I want to move folder "bla20150309" on drive D to "hello20150309" on drive E (I already read somewhere here that you need shutil instead of os.move if you do this kind of operation between different hard drives. The new folder hello20150309 on E does not exist yet and should be created with copy function.

The error I get so far when executing my code:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please use string format: "D:/bla{}".format(st)

Comment: Can you please give us the *full* exception you get?

Comment: Also, why not just use `datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')` instead of using `time.time()` and `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`? Even for `datetime.datetime` you can use `datetime.datetime.now()`, no need to involve the `time` module here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your directory names *before* passing them in to your function. What you have now:

```
copyDirectory("D:/bla%s","E:/hello%s") % (st, st)
```

is not going to work, you want:

```
copyDirectory("D:/bla%s" % st, "E:/hello%s" % st)
```

Otherwise you are trying to use the `%` operator on the `copyDirectory()` function *return value*, which happens to be `None` in this case.

Comment: Awwww it's always such minor things...that hurts. Thanks a lot man, works perfectly!